# непонятный результат массива

Tags: c, указатели

Угадать претендента которое выберет девушка. Код такой

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   int contestants[] = {1,2,3};
   int *choice =   contestants;
   contestants[0] = 2;
   contestants[1] = contestants[2];
   contestants[2] = *choice;
   prinf("я собираюсь выбрать претендента номер %i\n " , contestants[2]);
   return 0;
}
```

я вот никак не понимаю почему правильный ответ 2? Ведь ответ должен был быть 3. Подскажите как тут программа действует шаг за шагом и по какой логике программа выбирает 2?

Comment: Во-первых, объясните свою логику. Почему вдруг "ответ должен был быть 3"? Во-вторых, о каких еще "строковых массивах" идет речь в заголовке вопроса? Я в упор не вижу каким боком данный вопрос относится к каким-то "строковым массивам".

Comment: @AnT да простите пожалуйста я неправильно написал это не строковые массивы.Уже изменил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот в этой строке

```
contestants[2] = *choice;
```

вы заменяете **3** на **2**. Она равнозначна

```
contestants[2] = contestants[0];
```

Вот как будет меняться содержимое массива `contestants`

```
/*                           ячека  0  1  2 */
int contestants[] = {1,2,3};     /* 1, 2, 3 */
int *choice =   contestants;     /* 1, 2, 3 */
contestants[0] = 2;              /* 2, 2, 3 */
contestants[1] = contestants[2]; /* 2, 3, 3 */
contestants[2] = *choice;        /* 2, 3, 2 */
```

`choice` - это указатель на `int`. В вашем коде он указывает на первый элемент (индекс 0) массива `contestants`.

Comment: `choice` - это указатель на `int`. в вашем коде он указывает на первый элемент (индекс 0) массива `contestants`. он ничего не "держит". вы легко можете выйти за границу массива. почитайте про арифметику указателей.

Comment: спасибо большое за корректное объяснение